# Regarding MySQL and PHP versions

Tags: 7, installation

MySQL Server version: 5.0.77 and Current PHP version: 5.1.6

Does Drupal 7 support them?

Comment: I am going to close this question as too localized. It can be easily answered by looking at http://drupal.org/requirements, the official page about Drupal requirements.

Answer (score 4):

For Drupal 7 you'll need at least PHP 5.2.5. Have a look at http://drupal.org/requirements
One specific issue I had with PHP less than 5.2 was that I could not install http://drupal.org/project/drush so I had to upgrade. Probably I'd have more problems down the line if I hadn't.

The MySQL version you have is OK.

Answer (score 0):

No, you PHP version is too old.  Please see the [Drupal System Requirements](http://drupal.org/requirements) page for more details.